# PostgreSQL: Improving performance of data insert

Tags: postgresql, migration, performance, postgresql-performance

I would like to migrate all data from DB2 into PostgreSQL. How should I configure PostgreSQL for best performance during the initial migration (loading the data with INSERT statements)?
Should/could I desactivate WAL archiving?

Comment: There is a chapter dedicated to bulk/initial loading in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html

Comment: Is roughly 3 hours for 100'000'000 rows over multiple tables a good time?

Comment: I'm using WbCopy from SQL Workbench (http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-copy.html), I think this one uses INSERT Statements (with commit every 50'000 rows)? Do you still think that's too slow? It's around 16GB.

Comment: If you use `-usePgCopy` then this will be substantially faster (my test with 80 million rows was actually using WbCopy with `-usePgCopy`

Comment: Is `-usePgCopy`not only for WbImport? Because with WbCopy I go directly form one database to the other without going on the file system first (WbExport and then WbImport). I don't think this parameter is applicable for WbCopy?

Comment: You are right -usePgCopy is only available for WbImport. Typically it's a lot faster to use WbExport and then WbImport together with `-usePgCopy`. Copying the text files to the postgres server and then using `copy` in psql is the fastest way to do it